# What's the best way to care for this damaged plant?

Tags: containers, damage

This pot plant used to be double the size it is now, and was sitting on our outdoor table when some hungry cockatoos knocked it off and snapped off the other half of it.

[image: The plant]

I've since moved it to where they're unlikely to play with it, and have been watering it regularly hoping what's remaining will stay healthy. The leaves have been going a bit brown, but other than that it looks like it's neither dying nor thriving.

My question: is it likely that this will always be a half-plant? Is there anything I can do to 1) help it stay alive or even 2), help it grow to be more bushy again?

Comment: With the plant having a recent *trauma* be especially careful not to over/under water which will only stress the plant even more. Otherwise, cool looking plant, do you know what it is?

Comment: Thx @ᴉʞuǝ I'll be careful from now on - I think I was probably over watering it. Not sure what it is actually, I was given it as a gift! (that's moreso why I don't want it to die, for the sentimental value :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the image, I can tell you, it is still doing okay.

Secondly, I think you are doing everything you are supposed to, for now. Just like us, plants also need time to heal.

I'd recommend some compost or moss on the top to let more of the stem not be showing it is the way now. This is just something I do, and has worked to keep plants warm, retain moisture and also protects more of the stem and the root.

I am not able to tell how long it has been since the injury, but if it has been about 2 - 4 weeks, a very diluted 10-10-10 might help. Dilute as much as possible as plants may burn out faster when recovering.

Just a note, fertilizing is not a must right now, but it could help especially if you have been fertilizing the plant in the past.

Comment: Thanks so much both for the reassurance, and the actionable ideas. It's good to know that I'm not killing it by missing something!